# Files are being created in both branch and master while in the branch, why?

Tags: git

Basically if I do:

```
git checkout -b some-branch
rails generate model some_model
git checkout master
```

The same files generated above will also be available in master even though now I'm in master

Any reason for this? I thought making a new branch and creating new files there will just stay in that branch not be created in master as well.

Git config

```
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/user/repo.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

Comment: My bet is that the files generated by `rails` are ignored by Git. Therefore they aren't tracked and won't be removed from your working directory when you switch branches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the changes are not staged for commit, they're not specific to one branch. Meaning that Git doesn't change local changes.

You have two options:

- `git commit` change files - now after you `git checkout master` the changes are stick only the `some-branch`
- or `git stash`, move to master and when you `checkout some-branch` again, `git stash pop` the changes.

Comment: Yea, this works now and the changes are properly discarded from master if commited to the new branch. But for some reason I remember working on another project, this did not happen. I wouldn't need to git add . and git commit to discard changes from master.

Answer (score 1):

After `rails generate` you did not commit the files to the `some-branch` branch

When switching between branches, git does not change locally modified files or new files, unless there is a conflict.
If there is a conflict, it would not allow you to change branches and will suggest you stash or commit the changes.